# Magento 2: How to include auto-generated coupon code in Newsletter Subscribe email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, coupon-codes, variables, newsletter-subscriber

I want to include auto-generated coupon code that expires in 1 usage in newsletter subscribe email template.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By creating Email template programmatically. You can refer this solution https://store.magenest.com/blog/how-to-send-email-in-magento-2/